# How to Call a Function inside a Render in React/Jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, render, jsx

I want to call a function inside some embedded html. I tried the following but the function isn't called. Would this be the incorrect way of calling a function inside a render method?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class PatientTable extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
         checking:false
      };
        this.renderIcon = this.renderIcon.bind(this);
  }

  renderIcon(){
    console.log("came here")
    return(
      <div>Function called</div>
    )
  }

  render() {

   return (
       <div className="patient-container">

       {this.renderIcon}      

      </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

To call the function you have to add `()`

```
{this.renderIcon()}
```

Comment: it depends on your need, u can use either  `this.renderIcon()` or bind `this.renderIcon.bind(this)`.
is this correct? someone has written it below.

Comment: super minor note, for those using coffeescript, this would be `{@renderIcon()}`

Comment: I would recommend NOT doing this. 1.) `renderIcon` is/should be a component. `{this.renderIcon()}` is not how you use components in React. 2.) Your render is the source of truth for what your component is rendering. Abstracting that adds additional complexity.

Comment: Besides the fact that this answers is 3 years old I am not sure if I agree. IMHO I abstract this kind of things in separate components only if it is used in more than component. Some does it only after 3 reuses. THX for your comment on this old answer. Really appreciate it. All the best.

Comment: BTW. The uppercase is due to my correction chrome extension.

Comment: You mention not abstracting to a component unless you need to reuse it. What's the benefit here of abstracting this to a method? React components are just functions so why do it this way?

 I've mentioned a couple reasons why I wouldn't do this. What are the reasons to do this?

Comment: For those of you interested in why this is generally and objectively a bad practice, please see this: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component


It's worth mentioning that this answer is correct and does a great job of answering the posted question. I just think it's worth the effort of teaching people that if they find themselves writing code like this there is a reason NOT to do it.

Comment: @dknaack How to call the function only once?

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk e.g using the react hook useEffect.

Comment: @Galupuf One reason that can justify doing it IMO is that for example you have a condition and dont want to use a nested ternary:
`myConditionalRender(){
  if(loading) return <Loader />
  if(error) return <Error />
  return <MyComponent />
}`

and
`render(){
<div>
 ...more stuff ...
{myConditionalRenderer()}
}`

Comment: Why not just put that condition in a component? It achieves the same things without any of the bad side effects

Answer (score 19):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  buttonClick(){
    console.log("came here")
    
  }
  
  subComponent() {
    return (<div>Hello World</div>);
  }
  
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className="patient-container">
          <button onClick={this.buttonClick.bind(this)}>Click me</button>
          {this.subComponent()}
       </div>
     )
  }
  


}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

it depends on your need, u can use either  `this.renderIcon()` or [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) `this.renderIcon.bind(this)`

**UPDATE**

This is how you call a method outside the render.

```
buttonClick(){
    console.log("came here")
}

render() {
   return (
       <div className="patient-container">
          <button onClick={this.buttonClick.bind(this)}>Click me</button>
       </div>
   );
}
```

The recommended way is to write a separate component and import it.

Comment: this seems better since when you need to pass event or parameters this works

Answer (score 3):

The fix was at the accepted answer. Yet if someone wants to know why it  worked and why the implementation in the SO question didn't work,

First, **functions are first class objects in JavaScript**. That means they are treated like any other variable. Function can be passed as an argument to other functions, can be returned by another function and can be assigned as a value to a variable. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function).

So we use that variable to **invoke the function by adding parentheses ()** **at the end**.

One thing, 
If you have a function that returns a funtion and you just need to call that returned function, you can just have double paranthesis when you call the outer function ()().