# calling functions that return a JSX element in render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, coding-style

I am trying to reduce the length of the `render()`method to improve readability by calling class methods that contains isolated JSX elements.

The problem is that this technique won't work for more than one JSX element.

I embedded each element inside a `<View>` but it doesn't prevent this error

```
Invariant Violation : Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View,StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    }})

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
    header() {
        return  (
            <Text>header</Text>
        );

    }
    firstElement() {
        return (
                <Text>first element</Text>
        );

    }
    secondElement() {
        return (
            <Text>second element</Text>
        );

    }

    footer(){
        return (
            <Text>footer</Text>
        );
    }

    render() {

     let header  = this.header();
     let firstElement = this.firstElement();
     let secondElement= this.secondElement();
     let footer = this.footer();

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                header,
                firstElement,
                secondElement,
                footer,
            </View>

        );

    }


}
```

I am aware that the syntax in `render()`is not correct, it is to show you what i want the code to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error states that: you're having string text outside of a `<Text>` component. In your code, your header texts and commas ( , ) are the problem. Here is how to fix it:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        {header}
        {firstElement}
        {secondElement}
        {footer}
        // or you can directly use your functions
        /*
        {this.header()}
        {this.firstElement()}
        {this.secondElement()}
        {this.footer()}
        */
    </View>
);
```

P/s: In case you still don't understand why you got the error, you can try this:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
            header
            firstElement,
            secondElement,
            footer,
        </Text>
    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in your return You forgot to wrap your functions in {braces}. See [How to Call a Function inside a Render in React/Jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298136/how-to-call-a-function-inside-a-render-in-react-jsx) for a better explanation.

Change it to:

```
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {header}
        {firstElement}
        {secondElement}
        {footer}
      </View>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
         {header()}
         {firstElement()}
         {secondElement()}
         {footer()}
    </View>
);
```

but instead of doing that, you can just make their own components and import them.